# set dynamic states in app config when use ui router

Tags: angularjs

I use ui router in angular app, i want get states of ui router from server by call action that return state list in json format and then set state list item in stateProvider, how can & where i do this, this code is in app.Config for config state :

```
var list = ?????// how can get state list here?

var populateStates = function () {

    angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
       $stateProvider.state(item);
    };
};

populateStates();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple sample:

```
var list = [['home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/views/index',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          }],
          ['about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: '/views/about',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl'
          }]];

var populateStates = function () {
    angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
       $stateProvider.state(item[0], item[1]);
    };
};
```